# Android In App Purchase "Item that you have requested is not available for purchase" Error

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I am working on In App billing ans from last few days i have got stuck at this point.

I have created Product list for my App which is Saved as Draft on Market.
But when i run my Application on Device it gives me an error"Item that you have requested is not available for purchase".
Can some one help me out from this?

Comment: Yes.. Its resolved. I think in latest version (IAP V3) we avoid this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be because developers can't buy their own apps and in-app purchases. For some reasons, Google don't allow us to test them (which is very sad)

http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Android+Market/thread?tid=20d181aa6473a51d&hl=en