# "The item that you requested is not available for purchase" android In-App purchase error

Tags: android

I have implemented In-App Purchase in my application.

- I uploaded apk which is not published but saved as a draft.
- The developers email and the test account email is not the same.
- I also read this documentation

  http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/billing/billing_overview.html and http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html.

But not getting any ideas. Does anyone have any other ideas?

I got where I did mistake. Actually I am not used my Test Accounts. Now I am using Test Accounts but still there is a same problem so I have two question for this.

1. After save this again should I wait 2-3 Hour?
2. I uploaded APK of Version 2 so is it needed to change here ?

   ```
   private static Bundle makeRequestBundle(String method) {
       Bundle request = new Bundle();
       request.putString("BILLING_REQUEST", method);
       request.putInt("API_VERSION", 1);
       request.putString("PACKAGE_NAME", mContext.getPackageName());
       return request;
   }
   ```

Comment: check these links  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11020587/in-app-billing-item-requested-not-available-for-purchase  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8126153/android-in-app-purchase-item-that-you-have-requested-is-not-available-for-purch  http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=+%E2%80%9CThe+item+that+you+requested+is+not+available+for+purchase%E2%80%9D+android+In-App+purchase+errorhttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/11933149/the-item-you-have-requested-is-not-available-for-purchase

Comment: Make sure the product you added on play store is showing status as "active"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please make sure that The application does not need to be published, but the item does need to be published. 
Refer this links: http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html#billing-testing-static

Comment: Thanks for your response. Really I missing to publish my item. Now it is work.