# GooglePlay: The item you requested is not available for purchase

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play, in-app-billing

I am getting the following from the Google Play IAB API;

> The item you requested is not available for purchase

I have however successfully tested against static responses, and in addition, the following code returns `myProductId` in the list of available products;

```
ArrayList<String> skuList = new ArrayList<String> ();
skuList.add("myProductId");
Bundle querySkus = new Bundle();
querySkus.putStringArrayList("ITEM_ID_LIST", skuList);
Bundle skuDetails = service.getSkuDetails(3, activity.getPackageName(), "inapp", querySkus);
```

In addition I have;

- Published a beta APK
- Added a test user to the beta and opted in via the URL
- Logged on the device with the test user (gmail account)
- Pushed a signed APK with the same versioncode to the device
- Activated the product

The purchasing code I am using is;

```
Bundle buyIntentBundle = service.getBuyIntent(3, activity.getPackageName(), "myProductId", "inapp", "payload");
PendingIntent pendingIntent = buyIntentBundle.getParcelable("BUY_INTENT");
activity.startIntentSenderForResult(pendingIntent.getIntentSender(), 1001, new Intent(), Integer.valueOf(0), Integer.valueOf(0), Integer.valueOf(0));
```

Finally, logcat shows the following;

```
D/Finsky: [1] PurchaseFragment.onStateChange: Error: PurchaseError{type=3 subtype=0}
D/Finsky: [1] PurchaseFragment.onStateChange: Purchase failed: PurchaseError{type=3 subtype=0}
```

Whilst there are other questions related to this issue, none of them solve it for me;

1. [the item you requested is not available for purchase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13117081/the-item-you-requested-is-not-available-for-purchase)

   - Product is active
2. [The item you have requested is not available for purchase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11933149/the-item-you-have-requested-is-not-available-for-purchase)

   - Testing with Static Responses is successful for product `android.test.purchased`
3. [Android In App Purchase “Item that you have requested is not available for purchase” Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8126153/android-in-app-purchase-item-that-you-have-requested-is-not-available-for-purch)

   - Test user logged in

Comment: @SreeReddyMenon got excited there for a moment, but alas that resulted in the same issue.  The docs say regarding `developerPayload`: The developerPayload String is used to specify any additional arguments that you want Google Play to send back along with the purchase information.

Comment: may be different version code?

Comment: @SreeReddyMenon double checked: versioncode is same on both google play beta and in the source I deploy to the device.

Comment: apk is not from playstore ? You can install app from playstore right via opt-in URL ?

Comment: I am not sure ! But It should be.. please try once !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105562/discussion-between-stafford-williams-and-sree-reddy-menon).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

12 hours after my last test this was mysteriously working.  The symptoms were:

- Purchase unavailable if the application was installed to the device via ADB (release & signed)
- Purchase available as normal if the application was installed via Google Play (download)

What exactly fixed this i'm unsure.  Prior to waiting 12 hours I;

- Switched from using `IInAppBillingService` directly to using Google's `IABHelper`.  The immediate effect was still product unavailable for purchase, however the text was now displayed in red rather than black (what?) and the DFinsky error changed to subtype 4; `PurchaseError{type=3 subtype=4}`.  I also note that i was not using base64EncodedKey when using `IInAppBillingService` directly.
- Switched to multiple APKs (probably red-herring)
- Started an alpha test (was previously using a beta test only)
- Created a new gmail account and added it to testers

Even after all these changes, the issue was still occurring, so I went to bed, woke up this morning and with no further changes it just worked.  FML.

Answer (score 6):

**App must be installed from Playstore via opt-in URL.** this will help the app to authorize from `LICENSING & IN-APP BILLING`(Base64-encoded).

Edit : We can test the signed apk on device by installing using **adb** tool.  and

1.The **android:versionCode and android:versionName attributes** values in the AndroidManifest.xml of the application that you are installing matches the values of your APK in the Developer Console.

2.Your application is signed with the **same certificate** that you used for the APK that you uploaded to the Developer Console, before installing it on your device.

http://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/test-iab-app.html

Comment: [This page](http://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/test-iab-app.html) states it should be possible to "Install the APK file to your physical test device by using the `adb` tool."

Comment: I think you should add your email account ...under  Click Settings > Account details, then in the License Testing section, add the Google email addresses for your tester accounts.

Comment: Solved it, dunno how.  See my answer.

Comment: I know this answer is old, but I wanted to correct it a bit anyway.  You can sideload the APK onto the device using ADB, you don't have to download it from the store.  I frequently publish a build to the store and then make another one locally with matching versionCode.  Also the versionName doesn't matter for store testing, only the versionCode does.

Answer (score 0):

Opt-in url did it for me.  Send that to your user - it registers the user with their own play store app.  That's the middle man that seems to need to be notified that the person is a tester.

Comment: How do you do it exactly?

Answer (score 0):

After almost days of trying everything we accidentally made it work.
We had to "LEAVE THE PROGRAM" (link on the opt-in page) and RE-enter the program again. Then it finally worked...

Answer (score 0):

While purchasing an in-app subscription, I had all the things from below list at the right place.

1. Created signed apk and published to **alpha channel**
2. Added tester email ids to **license testing**
3. Added tester email ids to **closed track alpha testing**
4. **Opted in** to be a tester
5. Testing Id was **different** from developer account's id
6. Was on android device and **not on emulator**
7. Downloaded the app from play store

Still I was getting this error saying **"Item you were looking for could not be found"**.

After wasting 2-3 days I found out that it was only working if some **payment mode was setup in play store**.

While most of the answers are related to old IAB purchase and I implemented new billing client API which is -
**`implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:1.0'`**, it was not easy to find out the solution.

If this is the same case for some one, adding a payment mode might help you to overcome this error. You need to add one even for testing it, however, it will *not* be charged for email ids added as a license testers.