# in app billing, real transaction not working

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-billing

I have an alpha working version of my app. 
I have set the alpha open.
I successfully tested the in app billing with the test account (meaning the money is not charged to the test user).
I successfully tested the purchase with static response.

When i try to test the real payment it always say "the item is not available for purchase"

The version and the signature are ok.

Can you suggest what am i missing?

```
BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_ITEM_UNAVAILABLE    4   Requested product is not available for purchase
```

this is the returned code but i think has nothing to do with the real problem.
where can i find more information about the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have the reputation to comment yet, but have you tried making a purchase from a version of the app that was downloaded off of the play store instead of a version that was run from adb or android studio?

Here's someone who had a similar problem
[GooglePlay: The item you requested is not available for purchase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35833930/googleplay-the-item-you-requested-is-not-available-for-purchase)

Comment: I did try that but was not working. It started working the day after, probably the new alpha version took more than 2 hours to kick in.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a problem like this as well once - i.e. downloaded the app from the Play Store, with a test-account (aka no money purchase) it worked, but a real purchase with a non-test account failed.

For me the reason was that the merchant account linked to the Play Store was not set-up correctly. You might want to check that if your situation is similar.